# Distribution of number of coins (out of p) that return head n times in a row

Tags: probability

Ok, suppose I have $p$ coins ($p=19$). They turn head with probability $\pi=.6$.

Suppose I throw each coin $n=3$ times. I get this matrix (1 stand for heads):

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19
1:  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
2:  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1
3:  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
```

You can see that 5 of the 19 original coins returned head 3 times (out of 3 trial) in a row.

In general, if I start with $p$ coins, and run $n$ experiments, what is the distribution of the number of coins that return head $n$ times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see this as a Bernoulli/binomial experiment. For each coin there is a $0.6^3=0.216$ probability of success. The expected number of coins that are successful is then $E=0.216 \cdot 19= 4.104$, $SD=\sqrt{19 \cdot 0.216(1-0.216)}=1.793749$.

A quick simulation reveals

```
p=19
n=3

res=replicate(1e5,{
  sum(colSums(matrix(sample(0:1,p*n,prob=c(0.4,0.6),replace=T),nrow=n))==n)
})

> mean(res)
[1] 4.11498
> sd(res)
[1] 1.79474
```

In other words, it is the binomial distribution with parameters $n=19$ and $p=0.6^3$.

Comment: +1 though I would have put the last line first